# Downsample wav RIFF file using python

Tags: python, audio, wav

I'm trying to downsample a 16khz wav file to 8khz in python 2.6.  The file has RIFF header and is in a mulaw format and must remain in that format.

I've glanced at some things in [this big list of python stuff](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) and can't seem to find a simple library that will just change the sample rate of an audio file.

Any suggestions on a good python library to do this?

Comment: Behind the scenes, any tool that does this will really convert from mulaw to pcm then doing the SR conversion, then convert to pcm back to mulaw. Thus when you say it must "remain" in mulaw format, you really mean it must be converted back to that format. (Forgive me for picking nits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up installing [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) and then calling it via subprocess:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
soxCall = '/usr/local/bin/sox ' + infileName + \
                 ' ' + outfileName + ' rate 8k'
p = Popen(soxCall, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`audioop` looks designed to suit your needs.

Supports mu-law and looks like it can adjust the sample rate with [`audioop.ratecv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/audioop.html)